# UWP WebView UnsupportedUriSchemeIdentified event argument is 'exceptioned'

Tags: c#, webview, uri, uwp, url-scheme

I have webview and at some point it navigates to a scheme, the scheme is invalid. UnsupportedUriSchemeIdentified is thrown but its argument is broken, because the scheme is invalid and it could not parse it. But I need to get that broken scheme, how am I supposed to do it?
[image]

Comment: It seems the Uri is not in a valid Uri Format. Could you share some steps of reproducing this problem?

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT I have WebView for online payment, at the end of payment it tries to navigate to a URI which has json in it, in that json is written how the payment was done. So I need to get that json, but because there is json in URI it cant parse and throws that exception. How can I get URI?

Comment: I have the same problem with app protocols (app opening through web links). The scheme is invalid and I don't know how the app was activated. I don't know how to get the invalid scheme, I only get this exception. @Elvis: Example scheme://function=5 is wrong but I want to parse it in my app, not as url but as string!

Comment: @Adriano I have bad news... I have not found solution for that still....

Comment: @Adriano app opening through web links << what do you mean by that?

Comment: I was trying to create an app for windows using another protocol/scheme. mochabarcode://CALLBACK=http://mochasoft.com/test3.htm it works under android and ios, is invalid under windows.

Comment: @Adriano exactly same problem here, on ios and android it is ok but on uwp i cant find solution. If you find any, please write here as well